# not Gauss sum with the same magnitude

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Gauss sum is a sum of $p$ roots of unity with magnitude $\sqrt{p}$. Does another sum with such property exist?

More exactly. Let  $p$ be a prime number. $\zeta^p=1,\;\zeta\ne 1$. Causs sum: $G=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{i^2}$. We know that $|G|=\sqrt p$. I am looking for $a_0,\ldots,a_{p-1}\in N_0$: $∑a_i=p;|\sum_{i=0}^{p−1}a_i\zeta^i|=\sqrt p$

I would be surprised if this problem had not previously been studied. Has anybody seen it before?

Comment: I think you should be more specific about "this property": what exactly kind of object are you looking for? Also, there are lots of things that are commonly referred to as "Gauss sums".

Comment: If you want a generalization of the Gauss sum $\sum_{a \in F_p} \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) \zeta^{a}$, then wouldn't the right condition be $\sum_{i} a_i = 0?$ After all, the Legendre symbols sum to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A paper by Cavior](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2034027) does just that. It also follows from the method in [Elkies' answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135949/a-question-on-maps-from-mathbbz-p-mathbbz-to-itself) to a previous MO-question.